# Can TinyMCE turn a hyperlink automatically into an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, tinymce, wysiwyg

Let's say someone pastes a link in the tinymce. By default, it's just regular text. Is there a way to automatically sense it and apply a anchor to it? I want to this on the tinymce/javascript side.

Comment: look at their ms word filter. there you can see how to listen to paste and change text properly. as for the autolinking itself, it's not as trivial as it seems, but there is plenty of info on that online.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default, but it is possible using the [paste_preprocess setting](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste).
You will have to parse the content to identify hyperlinks and then you will need to replace them with anchors.
Then they will get added to the editors content.